# Why is Prometheus not a good choice for data with high cardinality?

Tags: monitoring, databases, prometheus, sql, data

I have a background in relational databases and new to Prometheus. I wonder why Prometheus is not a good choice for high cardinality data? Why do I need to use low cardinality data? It's exact opposite from SQL DBs.

What are the technical reason for that?

Comment: This is a FAQ: https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know, Prometheus doesn't mind high-cardinality **data**. What Prometheus doesn't like is high-cardinality **labels**.

Let's start with Prometheus official documentation, it gives a good high-level explanation why:

> CAUTION: Remember that every unique combination of key-value label
>   pairs represents a new time series, which can dramatically increase
>   the amount of data stored. Do not use labels to store dimensions with
>   high cardinality (many different label values), such as user IDs,
>   email addresses, or other unbounded sets of values.

- https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/naming/

The important part is really that **unique combinations of key-value** creates **new time series** in Prometheus.

For instance, if you store a gauge-type metric `registration_complete` that records the time a user took to complete his/her registration form, Prometheus won't have any issue with that. You'll have one time series that have hundred of thousand of values: one value for each user that registered (how long it took). You'll be able to graph that metric over time, get the p95, etc.

If you want to add *some* cardinality to it, you could add a label like `region`: US-east, Asia-Pacific, etc. You'll be able to graph all regions and compare them or maybe group them all. The number of regions is probably low (<10) and it is certainly bound. If on AWS, there's a fixed number of regions and they don't change much over time. Sure, AWS might add, remove or rename a region, but that's not changing by the minute and there's not thousands of them.

So to come back to what Prometheus advise against: you should not create high-cardinality labels. You should not add a `user_id` label to your `registration_complete` metric. If you do so, you'll have hundred of thousands of *different* time series, one for each user!, and they will all have only one data point. That's really the worst case scenario.

In this case, in order to graph the `registration_complete` metric over all labels, Prometheus will have to query all the individual time series (the X thousands of them) and aggregate all of them.

You said you come from a SQL background, so I'll attempt an analogy. Unique combination of key-value label pairs creating new time series in Prometheus amounts to individual tables in SQL. Having a label `user_id` equals to having one table per user_id.

Note: not all TSDB work the same way and I can't speak for them all.